# $(window).scrollTop(); does not fired quick enough

Tags: jquery, css, scrolltop

I been trying to make a header that will shrink by amount that you have scrolled and then stop and a certain point. There is also a logo that will move up within this

The only problem is `$(window).scrollTop();` does not fire quick enough. so if you scroll too fast the logo will be outside the header or the header might be pixels too big.

i cant think of a better way to do this.. any help or ideas would be appreciated

here is my code

```
var widgets = {
    header: function() {
        var $header = $('.header');
        var $logo = $('.header__title');
        var $headerHeight = $header.height();
        $(window).on('scroll resize', function(event) {
            var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
            var windowScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();


            if( windowScrollTop < 100) {
                $logo.css('margin-top','-'+(windowScrollTop)+'px'); 
            }

            if ( windowScrollTop < 230) {   
                $header.css('height',($headerHeight - windowScrollTop)+'px');
            }
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    widgets.header();
    .....
```

example is here http://jsfiddle.net/7wp51gu6/

Comment: sorry the position of the header is fix.. im just making jsfiddle to help more

Comment: yea fiddle will help a lot on this issue. Try to make sure a good portion of html is in there please.

Comment: this has now been added  http://jsfiddle.net/7wp51gu6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the final state on `else` of the two conditions

```
if (windowScrollTop < 100) {
    $logo.css('margin-top', '-' + (windowScrollTop) + 'px');
} else {
     $logo.css('margin-top', '-100px');
}

if (windowScrollTop < 230) {
    $header.css('height', ($headerHeight - windowScrollTop) + 'px');
} else {
    $header.css('height', ($headerHeight - 230) + 'px');
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/7wp51gu6/7/

Comment: Thank you seems to work a treat and still got the smooth animation

Answer (score 1):

I made some quick changes and need some quick feedback from you, but check this fiddle out...

http://jsfiddle.net/7wp51gu6/6/

I updated the script here only:

```
if (windowScrollTop >= 100) {
    $logo.css('margin-top', '-100px');
}else{
    $logo.css('margin-top',0);
}
```

It basically sets it to the top where you want it when it is greater than or equal to 100. Also sets it back when you are at the top which is where you want it.

Also made a change to some css that pushes your primary content down 312px. Check that out as well. That isn't 100% necessary just assuming based on your current display something you will need in the future.

Comment: Thank you i can see what you done.. i did have that padding set in my mian code just forgot to add it to this.. thanks for the help

Comment: Not hurt at all you didn't choose me @Richy... I understand... #nothurtatall #cryingalittle... :P

Comment: #HUG. only reason is, i was being lazy, and that one worked out the box. You both did the same thing, shame I cant pick two